# google-cloud-storage permission denied in google-app-engine standard

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-storage

Trying to access google cloud storage bucket from inside google app engine standard running flask using the [client library for Python](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/index.html) .

(**edit**) not officially supported. see answer for workaround.

code looks something like this..

```
from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import storage

# UNCOMMENT THIS FOR SOLUTION
#import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine
#requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/endpoint', methods=['POST', 'PUT'])
def upload_to_storage():
    try:

      # file info
      filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
      mimetype = file.content_type

      # connect to bucket
      client = storage.Client(project='projectName')
      bucket = client.get_bucket('bucketName')

      # upload file to bucket
      blob = storage.Blob(filename, bucket)
      blob.upload_from_file(file, content_type=mimetype, num_retries=10)

      return jsonify({'status':200})

    except:

      return jsonify({'status':500})
```

error message:

('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))

Comment: App engine apps run as a particular service account. Does your app engine app's service account have permission to do stuff with the bucket 'my-bucket'?

Comment: yep, service account has permission. I think what was happening was I needed to make sure Requests uses URLFetch

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**

(edit) google.cloud.storage is not officially supported in GAE standard, to get authentication to work ([google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#the-app-engine-standard-environment)) need to do a few extra steps:

**update requirements.txt**

> requests-toolbelt

assuming you are using a directory called 'lib' to vendor in 3rd party libraries

`$ pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib`

**update appengine_config.py**

`from google.appengine.ext import vendor 
vendor.add('lib')`

**update main.py (or equivalent)**

`import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine
requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()`

**update app.yaml**

`libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest`

Comment: it is not question info, it is the answer

Comment: (edited answer to make it clear I am not just adding extra question info)

Comment: This answer was the right one to complete the full monkeypatching to make google-cloud-storage work. It's needed when you need to access an online bucket from devserver.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the google.cloud.storage modules, use the GCS client designed specifically for operating within GAE standard:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#downloading_the_client_library.
This client will implicitly perform the authentication avoiding that 'Permission denied' error.

The following page demonstrates how to write using the client: h[ttps://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#writing_to_cloud_storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#writing_to_cloud_storage). The only missing information is that the "filename" in the example is in the format "//". The write operation takes care of locating and writing to the correct bucket(You do not need to retrieve the bucket beforehand).

Comment: Sometimes you need to access an online bucket from development server (read only operations are safe). You can't do this with standard dev server. The answer above is a great workaround.